# How long does it take for backlinks to appear if you submit the page yourself?

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console

I have some new backlinks to my website online on other websites. I submitted the pages using webmaster tools > submit url so that googlebot would crawl the pages faster.This was 24 hours ago and I checked the backlinks in moz site explorer and in webmaster console but they still haven't showed up.

How long would this usually take for webmaster tools? And for open site explorer would this take the same amount of time or longer?

Is this the best way to check for backlinks?

Answer (score 2):

Even after submitting a URL there is still a delay in processing the crawl. This can sometimes take up to two weeks. Using the submit URL module in GWT doesn't accelerate or override the standard indexing of a site, rather it is simply a tool to let Google know that a page may need to be re-indexed. 24 hours isn't much time at all to let Google reindex a page, allow at least a week or two and you should see the details updated in GWT automatically.